# How do I move the Hub Navigation bar to the page header?

Tags: powershell, design

I have made a team-site template as the main site of our organisation's intranet frontpage, as well as the sites for each department,  and I would like to replicate the communication site navigation layout by moving the 'Hub navigation' to the site header.

See the image below for illustration. [image: Illustration of request]

Is it possible to make this adjustment using a Powershell or Javascript command?

Comment: This might not be possible with PowerShell or SharePoint OOTB functionalities. But you can do some DOM manipulation using [SPFX extensions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/overview-extensions) and achieve this.

Comment: DOM manipulation of these elements would not be supported and any solution would likely break.